# Android Layouts - layout-normal vs layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any difference in the way Android handles layouts in the "layout-normal" vs "layout" folders?  If I have a device that is considered layout-small, which folder will it look at if those are the only two options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, In the example you've given it will take from "layout" first.

When determining where to pull resources from it will check the layout-size folder that matches the device first (i.e. small device will check layout-small first), if the specific resource in question isn't available there then it will check the plain "layout". If and only if the resource is still not available there will it start to check in "layout-size" folders that do not match the device that it is currently running on.

**EDIT:** Just tested on a small device. My findings re-affirm how I thought it would work. It will definitely take from plain layout instead of layout-normal on a small device if the resource exists in both.

Comment: Also note that it can be hierarchical - if you have layout-small-port it will look there before going on to layout-small -> layout etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Tim. I ended up finding this resource as well which details how android picks which layout to use. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2